# How to make jquery autocomplete search on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-autocomplete

i am working with jquery atocomplete and want to search the suggestion on click like google youtube. but it's not working. here is html code

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 488px; left: 248px; width: 542px;">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-6" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Activity</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Apply online</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and jquery is here

```
    $( "#site-search-query" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(res, request.term);
    response(results.slice(0, 4));
}
```

any suggestion regarding this ?

Answer (score 4):

In the click handler call the [search-method](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) of autocomplete - You need to set the [minLength-option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) to `0` to make it work

```
$("#site-search-query").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(res, request.term);
        response(results.slice(0, 4));
    },
    minLength: 0
}).click(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete('search')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dhLCR/)

Comment: This still queries when a character is typed. How can I get it to query only when clicking on a specific selector?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#site-search-query" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(res, request.term);
    response(results.slice(0, 4));
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    //Your search function
    }
})
```